# Does AppEngine support OAuth 2.0?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

Does Google AppEngine support OAuth 2.0?  And, if so, can you suggest a good tutorial?

Comment: How do you want to use OAuth 2?

Comment: I have limited experience of using OAuth (1 or 2) with AppEngine, and having heard that 2.0 is the latest, wanted to confirm what the current state of play is before putting some effort into developing using it.

Comment: OK, let me ask a more specific question: do you want to be an OAuth consumer (access OAuth-protected APIs), OAuth producer (verify OAuth tokens and serve data based on those credentials), or both?

Comment: At this point, it would be as a OAuth consumer.

Comment: There are third party libraries for OAuth2 consumers. What runtime are you developing for? E.g. Go, Python, Java

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, and they are moving access to their APIs to use 2.0.  I have not come across any great tutorials out there but Google is building on their documentation for this.  They do have code samples for non App Engine stuff out there.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Answer (score 1):

For Google APIs there are libraries in:

- [Python](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/)
- [Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)
- [Go](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/)

that you can use on App Engine to access Google APIs using OAuth 2.0. The Python and Java libraries are built on top of a generic library that enables OAuth 2.0 functionality, so if you're accessing non-Google APIs that may be helpful. There may be libraries for other API platforms as well, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: It may make sense to update this answer in light of Google Cloud Endpoints.